# How do I rotate an iPhone photo on my iPhone without losing EXIF data?

Tags: iphone, ios, photos, image-editing, exif

I have iOS 4.3.3.

Are there any apps or methods that allow simple rotating of an iPhone photo (taken where the level sensor picked the wrong orientation), without losing the EXIF information?

Using ExifWizard app, it seems Adobe PS Express and PerfectPhoto both lose the original exif data upon rotate and save.

I know iOS 5 has a built in rotate feature but I'm not running iOS 5 here.

Answer (score 1):

[Photogene2](http://www.mobile-pond.com/MobilePond/photogene/photogene2-for-iphone/) is a handy iOS photo editor and has an EXIF viewer in app. Currently $0.99

Comment: Highly recommended for more than just rotation. Along with Snapseed, it's of my two *go to* iPhone photo apps. (And I use the original Photogene on the iPad.)

Answer (score 0):

[PhotoForge2](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/photoforge2/id435789422?mt=8) is an iOS photo editor that will rotate the photo and preserve the EXIF data (although it does reorder it a bit in ExifWizard, it's all still there).  It's usually $2.99 in the App Store, but it is currently on sale for $1.99.